# GNU download - testing success of download version

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

a really basic question but I can't think clearly.  I have download GNU Make  ( make-4.0.tar.oz ) from   http://ftp.org.gnu/make/.  Double clicked on the downloaded file.  How do I tell if I have installed it ?     Downloading this software as part of trying to download jStat for which GNU is a dependency ( from https://github.com/jstat/jstat).  Running a Mac OS X operating system.
any help really welcome.
Pierre

Comment: `which make` will help you.

Answer (score 0):

make -v 
gives GNU Make 3.81
I asked the question too early - apologies